# Experiences with D-programming-language

Tags: d

Has someone here ever had experience with the [D programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29)?

It seems to have many nice features but will it ever reach the popularity of those currently widespread languages like C++, Java or C#?

So is it worth learning or is it an isolated language with minor prospects.

Comment: It's worth learning because it has some nice feature but it is not worth investing to write real world apps because the tooling and library are crap.  It's just not organized well and far too many subtle issues with things that waste a lot more time than one realizes. No business wants that. I think many can subconsciously sense that it's a can of worms. It's like buying a porche online for 10k that looks amazing and runs great... but when you drive it for a month you start noticing things not running right... then, eventually, things start falling apart.

Comment: I think the best use for D is to do certain high level algorithms and tools that are not large or interconnected, then use those from other languages.  This way one spends less in D but can use it's powerful features more advantageously. Unfortunately this is tricky because of the interop between it and other languages(You'll end up writing in C rather than C++ because templates do not translate between the two... although possibly one could overcome that with some wrappers that work well).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I spent a few days playing with D to see how it compares to C++ and java. It is positioned as another way to achieve the same things C++ does, but without all the undefined behaviour, and with the addition of a garbage collector, foreach loop, and some other modern niceties. It compiles to native code so you get access to all the usual optimisations that can occur from this scenario.

The entire C language is encapsulated as a subset of D as the lower level building blocks from which much of the language is constructed. This can help with portability, but also prevents D from evolving into single consistent methodology.

The ability to run any C function natively in D opens up the realm of possibility to include systems programming - operating systems, drivers, etc.

There are two commonly used class frameworks in D. The default is Phobos, which is rather spartan and simple in design, allowing you to create the structures you need, but providing few large or complex building blocks. The other is [Tango](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango), which is reminiscent of the java class library and contains a much more complete framework. There is also a project to allow interoperability of the two libraries.

In my experience, D is quite a nice language for coding, having a lot in common with C# and java, and allowing access to the raw machinery through C and even assembly interop. The main limitation I see is a lack of good development tools support. There are some IDEs and plugins out there, but nothing very complete, so you might be better off with a text editor and a command line build tool in the meantime.

There are two versions of the language, D1 and D2. D1 is better supported by frameworks and compilers for now, and D2 has added a few convenience features that make the language easier to deal with and use.

**Update (June 2009):**
I have recently been looking into D again and thought I should draw attention to [DSource](http://www.dsource.org/projects/), which now has a number of different compiler projects, and is the home of the Tango library, various bindings, several GUI toolkits, and a couple of IDEs. Some of the projects were abandoned in their infancy, but I believe there are quite a few going strong today, and making good progress. At this stage, it looks very much like the success of D will be determined by the open source movement far more than by its progenitors.

**Update (February 2012)**
While I haven't looked much at D since my last edit, I will note that D2 is out now, with the support of a great book, [The D Programming Language](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/tdpl/). Typical of Alexandrescu, it exposes a lot of detail of the template system, including template constraints, which make D a much more expressive and type-safe tool than the current state of C++.

Other than reading the book, I have had no contact with the D language or its tools and community since 2009 so I can't comment on their maturation or growth to date. I am aware of a small cadre of professional programmers that wish they were allowed to use the language at work, but most of us are generally stuck with C++ and other popular languages in the areas where D should be at its best.

Comment: +1.  A fair assessment of the current state of affairs, though rapid progress is being made on the toolchain front.  See LDC (http://www.dsource.org/projects/ldc) and Descent (An Eclipse plugin:  http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent).

Comment: @dsimcha: Ditto on the tool chain comment, it's improving rapidly. If the tool chain were even 80% as good for D as for C++, then I think C++ would rapidly become a legacy language. Given time, I think it will get there.

Comment: @BCS: I agree, the fact that D has even this level of support this early into it's life may be an indicator of it's future success.

Comment: +1 Very instructive. I would not mind a new edit 3 years later!

Comment: FWIW: the development in D has picked up in the last year or so. The reference compiler is now open source (as in !"closed source", but not FOSS) and a full build-able source is up on github. This has allowed a number of people to start contributing. The developers are also starting to worry about regression counts and other "production" and "stability" issues so it's moving away from beta status.

Comment: C isn't a subset of D. Most non-trivial C programs wouldn't compile with a D compiler.

Comment: I'm sure I read near the time that the D compiler also contained a full C implementation. Perhaps not, but in any case, it is worth noting that The current D spec does not claim to superset the C lanugage, although it does provide extensive interop support. http://www.d-programming-language.org/interfaceToC.html

Comment: Let's talk GUI with D. It's Sept 2015. Although we can still use GtkD, try and draw various kinds of charts -- it's complex to do that and you have to do a lot by hand. There are people working on the Chromium project to give D a GUI. However, that's still fairly undocumented and not ready for primetime yet. I think if the D integration with Chromium would get some more players, the D language would take off. D has so many advantages versus the masochistic C++.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at things like language popularity, etc I have found Tiobe to be a good resource http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

As you can see D is in the top 20.

Comment: I just looked at it now (Feb 2012) and unfortunately it is now at 40. That said, it is still above Haskell, Go, Eiffel, Clojure, Scala and other much talked about languages. According to Tiobe, one of the up and coming languages is LOGO!!

Comment: It is back up to only 39 :(

Comment: August 2014, shot up to 28. I wonder why assembly is so popular.

Comment: September 2017, moved up to 24.